# How Can I Test an Imported Function With Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a React app, and I'm trying to build out some unit tests.
I got most of this test working, but I still can't figure out how to test one line using jest. I can't tell if it's because of the package I imported or if I'm doing something else incorrectly.

LogOutForDisagreement.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ClipboardClip from './../ClipboardClip';

const store = require('store2');

function LogOutForDisagreement(props) {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.onChange(
            props.props.user = {
                loggedIn: false,
                email: '',
                password: '',
                firstName: ''
            },
        );
        store.clearAll();
        //sessionStorage.clear();

    };
    return (
        <div id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className}>
            <Form className="form">
                <ClipboardClip />
                <div className="centeredPaper">
                    <p>Sorry, you must agree to our privacy policy to access the site. You must now log out and log back in to agree to the terms.</p>
                    <Button id="logOutForDisagreement" type="" onClick={handleClick}>
                        Log Out
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LogOutForDisagreement;
```

LogOutForDisagreement.test.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import LogOutForDisagreement from './LogOutForDisagreement';

const store = require('store2');

let props = {
  props:
  {
    user: {
      loggedIn: false,
      email: 'email@example.com',
      password:   '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',
      firstName: 'FirstName'
    },
    className: "logOutForDisagreement"
  }
};
//You don't need the props for everything, just the className, but I'm leaving them here for now. 


describe('Test the log out for disagreement button', () => {

  it('renders correctly enzyme and has onclick', async () => {
    console.log("This is the store at the begining after initial load: {" + Object.entries(sessionStorage).map(([key, val] = sessionItem) => {
      return `${key}: ${val}`}) + "}");

    const { getByText } = render(<LogOutForDisagreement id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className} />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'clearAll');

    await fireEvent.click(getByText("Log Out"));
    
    console.log("This is in the store after the event fires: {" + Object.entries(sessionStorage).map(([key, val] = sessionItem) => {
      return `${key}: ${val}`}) + "}");

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    expect(toJson(getByText)).toMatchSnapshot();
    //spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

I still get an error that says the following:

```bash
Test the log out for disagreement button › renders correctly enzyme and has onclick

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      37 |       return `${key}: ${val}`}) + "}");
      38 |
    > 39 |     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                 ^
      40 |
      41 |     expect(toJson(getByText)).toMatchSnapshot();
      42 |     //spy.mockRestore();
...
--------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|----------------------------------
File                                        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
--------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|--------------------
...
 LogOutForDisagreement.js                  |   83.33 |      100 |     100 |   83.33 | 19
```

I'm just missing one line. Does anyone know how to get 100% test coverage on this? I know this is picky, but I use this same package in a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting the answer for anyone who runs into a similar issue. I used a tutorial from youtube.com that also used a third party library (axios) and mocked the built in axios functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gA-uNj2FgdM. I also had to pass the props down to the component and include onChange in the component, but now I have 100% test coverage.
LogOutForDisagreement.test.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import LogOutForDisagreement from './LogOutForDisagreement';

import mockStore from 'store2'; 

jest.mock('store2');

mockStore.clearAll(() => Promise.resolve({}));

let props = {
  props:
  {
    user: {
      loggedIn: false,
      email: 'email@example.com',
      password:'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',
      firstName: 'FirstName'
    },
    className: "logOutForDisagreement"
  }
};
//You don't need the props for everything, just the className, but I'm leaving them h

describe('Test the log out for disagreement button', () => {

  it('renders correctly enzyme and has onclick', async () => {
    
    const { getByText } = render(<LogOutForDisagreement id="logOutForDisagreementClipboard" className={props.className} props={props} onChange={jest.fn()} />);
    
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {
      name: /log out/i
    }));

    //await expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockStore.clearAll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(toJson(getByText)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Code Coverage

```bash
--------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|----------------------------------
File                                        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
--------------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|----------------------------------
All files                                   |   25.95 |     8.06 |   18.94 |   26.33 |
 src/components/privacyPolicyComponents     |      25 |        0 |   21.05 |      25 |
  LogOutForDisagreement.js                  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |
```

Does anyone know why it reports that I called the function twice now? Should I just use `toHaveBeenCalled`? I still get an error that it got called twice.

```bash
 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 2
```